Does a heat of formation change in a magnetic field?
Can anyone tell me if the heat of formation changes in a magnetic field?
And if so, can someone tell me where I can find these values? Or how I can calculate it? (for example "standard" enthalphy of heat of formation of $\ce{H2O}$ in a magnetic field of 1 Tesla)

I assume eventual difference would be well within uncertainty of standard enthalpies of formation. // $\Delta_\text{f} H^{\circ} = \Delta H_{\text{reactants}\  0 \to \pu{1 T}} + \Delta_\text{f} H^{\circ}\text{1 T} + \Delta H{\text{products}\  1 \to \pu{0 T}}$

IMHO, the only chance of change detection is if there are changes for compounds between being para- and diamagnetic, or during reactions involving ferro/ferri-/antiferromagnetics.

Unless you are writing a sequel to "Starquake", there is no difference.

Interesting question. A magnetic field strongly affects the rate of ortho <-> para hydrogen conversion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_isomers_of_hydrogen, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S007968161300035X), but it might not affect the heat  of formation.

My first thought was you might be able to do something if one of the reactants undergoes significant Magnetostriction , but the volume changes are tiny
